# Inherit scripts from parent to childtheme

Tags: javascript, child-theme

So i got a parenttheme that enques scripts like this:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/dist/modernizr.min.js', array(), '1.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/dist/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0', false );
    wp_register_script( 'scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/dist/scripts.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic', array(), '1', 'screen,projection' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array(), '1', 'screen,projection' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

I shuld add that I am using gulp to minify the above scripts and put them in the `dist`-folder.

Everything works fine in the parent-theme but I have now created a child-theme and the the scripts are not found.

The console logs:

```
http://localhost:3000/PARENT/wp-content/themes/CHILD/assets/js/dist/jquery.min.js?ver=1.0 - 404
```

All I have in my child-theme is 2 files:

style.css:
/*

```
 Theme Name:     child
 Description:    parent child theme
 Template:       parent
 Version:        1.0.0
*/
```

and functions.php:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
 ?>
```

I do not know what causes the error but some thoughts i have had are:

1. Since im using gulp to minify the scripts, maybe they are not yet created when the child-theme searches for them.
2. As mentioned above the code looks for the files in:
   the child-theme:

ttp://localhost:3000/PARENT/wp-content/themes/CHILD/assets/js/dist/jquery.min.js?ver=1.0 -

Maybe it should look for the files in the parent?

Help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because parent theme using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to call script. By this function it is searching for file in your child theme folder (bcause child theme's style.css is using by active theme) where no such files present. This function search those theme folder whose style.css file is using in active theme. Right now your child theme is active (in appearance > theme).

If you want to call that script then use script in your child theme's functions.php like this

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/dist/modernizr.min.js', array(), '1.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/dist/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0', false );
    wp_register_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/dist/scripts.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic', array(), '1', 'screen,projection' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', array(), '1', 'screen,projection' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

In above code I just replace `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` with `get_template_directory_uri()`.

`get_template_directory_uri()` function will search for file in parent theme.